# How can I create my own theme for vs code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, themes

How can I create my own theme for vs code?
change color & syntax colors?

Comment: read the extension author guide for VSC, be aware it is a lot of work, a lot of names to give a color

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Once you have tweaked your theme colors using
> `workbench.colorCustomizations` and `editor.tokenColorCustomizations`,
> it's time to create the actual theme.
>
> 1. Generate a theme file using the **Developer: Generate Color Theme from Current Settings** command from the **Command Palette**
> 2. Use VS Code's [Yeoman](https://yeoman.io) extension generator to generate a new theme extension:
>
>    `bash npm install -g yo generator-code yo code`
> 3. If you customized a theme as described above, select 'Start fresh'.
> 4. Copy the theme file generated from your settings to the new extension.
>
> You can also use an existing TextMate theme by telling the extension
> generator to import a TextMate theme file (.tmTheme) and package it
> for use in VS Code. Alternatively, if you have already downloaded the
> theme, replace the `tokenColors` section with a link to the `.tmTheme`
> file to use.
>
> ```json
> {
>   "type": "dark",
>   "colors": {
>     "editor.background": "#1e1e1e",
>     "editor.foreground": "#d4d4d4",
>     "editorIndentGuide.background": "#404040",
>     "editorRuler.foreground": "#333333",
>     "activityBarBadge.background": "#007acc",
>     "sideBarTitle.foreground": "#bbbbbb"
>   },
>   "tokenColors": "./Diner.tmTheme"
> }
> ```
>
> **Tip:** Give your color definition file the `-color-theme.json` suffix and you will get hovers, code completion, color decorators, and
> color pickers when editing.

**Source:** [Create a new Color Theme](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/color-theme#create-a-new-color-theme)

Answer (score 1):

Using this service would help a lot to visualize what is what & where!:

https://themes.vscode.one/